# How to read information from a XML file c++

Tags: c++, attributes, nodes, rapidxml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rapidxml: how to iterate through nodes? Leaves out last sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203325/rapidxml-how-to-iterate-through-nodes-leaves-out-last-sibling)

Im trying to reas some information from a XML file using rapidXML but cant get it to work.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<MODESMESSAGE>
   <DATETIME>20070622141943</DATETIME>
   <MODES>400F2B</MODES>
   <CALLSIGN>BAW134</CALLSIGN>
   <ALTITUDE>120300</ALTITUDE>
   <GROUNDSPEED>451</GROUNDSPEED>
   <TRACK>234</TRACK>
   <VRATE>0</VRATE>
   <AIRSPEED></AIRSPEED>
   <LATITUDE>-14.1102</LATITUDE>
   <LONGITUDE>-31.5789</LONGITUDE>
</MODESMESSAGE>
```

And this is how my code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace rapidxml;
using namespace std;

xml_document<> doc;    // character type defaults to char

int main(){
    ifstream myfile("test.xml");
    xml_document<> doc;
    vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>( ));
    buffer.push_back('\0');
    doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);
    xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node();
    xml_attribute<> *att = node->first_attribute();
    cout << node->name();
    cout << att->name(); 
}
```

I can compile the program but when I run it it just stops working. I can get the first node(MODEMESSAGE) but cant get the the rest of them, ie DATETIME or MODES.

What should I do?

Comment: I think you should use a loop to iterate over nodes.

Answer (score 1):

"DATETIME" and "MODES" are inner nodes to "MODEMESSAGE", therefore you should access them like this:

```
xml_node<> *messagenode = doc.first_node("MODEMESSAGE");
xml_node<> *datetimenode = messagenode->first_node("DATETIME");
xml_node<> *modesnode = messagenode->first_node("MODES");
```